# .css() jquery not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm attempting to apply the height of window to the max-height of a particular div.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        console.log('Initial Window height:', $(window).height());
        $('.wordboard').css({ "max-height": ($(window).height()-150) + 'px' });
        //console.log($('.wordboard').css({"max-height": ($(window).height() - 150) + 'px'}));


        console.log("Initial max height of $('.wordboard'): ", $('.wordboard').css("max-height"));
        $(window).resize(function(){
            $('.wordboard').css({ "max-height": ($('body').height()-150) + 'px' });
            console.log("$('.wordboard').css('max-height')",$('.wordboard').css('max-height'));
        });

    });
```

However, the my website is loaded: the max-height isn't applied. The result in the console is when the website is loaded is:

```
Initial Window height: 550
script.js:28 Initial max height of $('.wordboard'):  undefined
(After i resize the window, the effect is now apply. However, I want to apply as soon as the window is loaded)

script.js:31 $('.wordboard').css('max-height') 718px
script.js:31 $('.wordboard').css('max-height') 723px
script.js:31 $('.wordboard').css('max-height') 728px
script.js:31 $('.wordboard').css('max-height') 733px
```

Comment: Might have something to do with the '???px' not being wrapped in quotes.

Comment: Can you provide jsFiddle replicating your issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only solution comes in mind is that at time you call your snippet on document ready pseudo event, your element(s) `.wordboard` doesn't exist in the DOM. You are surely (or a plugin) adding it dynamically.

***EDIT:*** just check it:

```
$(function(){console.log($(".wordboard").length);});
```

If displaying `0`, you know from where comes from your issue.

Comment: Thanks. That's must be the problem.

Comment: Yeh. Turn out I just need to move the script to the bottom of the page

Answer (score 3):

This is the correct way.

```
$('.wordboard').css('max-height',"723px");
```

Comment: Why this fixed number? Any particular reason?

Comment: this is also the correct. $('.wordboard').css({ "max-height": ($(window).height()-150) + 'px' });

Comment: Not sure how this address OP's issue?!

Answer (score 0):

You have the code inside an event, the `resize` event.

It will only execute when that event is triggered. (As you verified)

Now, you have 2 options:

1. Trigger the `resize` event:
   `$(window).resize(function(){ [...] }).resize();`
   Yes, just add `.resize()` after the event declaration. It's that simple!
2. Duplicate the code:
   `$(window).resize(function(){ [...] });
   $('.wordboard').css({ "max-height": ($('body').height()-150) + 'px' });`